# Disable admin bar reload in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

When users navigate the site I do not want the WordPress admin bar to reload. I want it to be a permanent fixture. Everything else may reload.

How can I achieve this?

For all the confusion I am clarifying that I do NOT want to disable the admin bar. I want it not to refesh as user navigated the site so it down not have to reload but be as a permanent feature. Go example, in gmail the only the main contents reload but the header and sidebars do not reload

Comment: If you want the WP admin bar to not reload you need to make everything else load with ajax which not that easy to do when you want all of your website's elements to work that way. It's not really practical.
You can get rid of the admin bar for your users if it bothers you.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps, removes admin bar other than administrator

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar');
function remove_admin_bar() 
{

    if (!current_user_can('administrator') && !is_admin()) 
    {
    show_admin_bar(false);
    }

}
```